# Accessing Text File in Non-Admin mode

Tags: c#

I have a text file in Program Files. I cannot write it from a C# application while running in non-admin mode.

I am using this snippet

```
TextReader read = new StreamReader("C:\Program Files\......\link");
```

It is throwing an error that the access to the file is denied, however I can read it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to a file can be different for reading and writing. As a non-admin, it's normal to be able to read files in Program Files, but not be able to write them.

If the file is a setting for the current user, you should put it in a folder under the AppData folder. You can find the AppData folder's location by calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData))`

If the file is a setting for all users on the computer, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData))`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx for a list of other possible special folder locations.

Answer (score 1):

Non-admin users don't have write access to files in `C:\Program Files` by default. If you want  to write to a file that is accessible to all users, you should create it in `C:\ProgramData`.

Answer (score 0):

In .net there is a class File 
through which you can use the method
File.read(file path)
this return a string 
so you can easily manage it
it also works in a non admin mode

Comment: That doesn't really address the problem, does it?